# Using mFusedLocationClient to get current location within a firebase service

Tags: java, android, firebase, location

I'm new to java/android dev so my code may be dumb.

I have a website which uses google maps, I have a button on the website which sends a push cURL message to a specific device using firebase. I want the device to then get the current location and update my database.

I'm using MyFirebaseMessagingService and onMessageReceived to grab the cURL message and that all works fine, it breaks when I start going into the location code. I had various errors so I tried creating a class for getting the location then calling a method of that class within my service.

The class:

```
 public class LocationMedium {

private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private Context mContext;

public LocationMedium(Context context) {
    mContext=context;
}


public void getLocation() 
{
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //currently pointless

        //return;
    }


    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener((Activity)mContext, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    Log.d("mytag", "2222");
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                        double x = location.getLatitude();
                        double y = location.getLongitude();


                        Log.d("mytag1", String.valueOf(x));

                        Log.d("mytag2", String.valueOf(y));
                        String user = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getString("USERNAME", "none");
                        MyFirebaseInstanceIDService firebase = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService();
                        firebase.onDeadline(user, x, y);


                    } else //no location found
                    {
                        String user = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getString("USERNAME", "none");
                        MyFirebaseInstanceIDService firebase = new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService();
                        firebase.onDeadline(user, 0, 0);
                        Log.d("mytag", "hmm");
                    }
                }
            });
    //END OF LOCATION

    Log.d("mytag", "theend");


}//end of run
```

}

And I call it with this from the MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
        if (Objects.equals(user, " location ")) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LocationMedium task = new LocationMedium(context);
                 task.getLocation();
            }
        });
    }
```

The error with this I get is:

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

And it appears to be on this line:

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
```

I tried removing the (Activity) bit from:

```
 .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) mContext, new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
```

and changing it to:

```
 .addOnSuccessListener(mContext, new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
```

but then I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'addOnSuccessListener...'
```

Perhaps I'm going about this completely the wrong way. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
.addOnSuccessListener(mContext, new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
```

Replace the above code with this,

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>()
```

Worked for me.